# Why my NavigationBar cannot be totally transparent?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-navigation-bar

In my theme.xml, when I set the below

```
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">#00000000</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#00000000</item>
```

My `statusBar` is now totally transparent. But my `navigationBar` is still not totally transparent. Why? How can I make my `navigationBar` totally transparent (as I want to put a different color beneath it, and not wanted it to pollute by the semi-transparent of it)

[image]

Comment: Can hiding the navigation bar (& status bar) as youtube/exoplayer be the solution to it other than making it completely transparent? The user should have accessibility to enable it to reappear on touch, to my knowledge. If so, then there are two flags to toggle between.

Comment: I don't want to hide it away totally. I will put a dark color beneath it to make it visible. But the semi-transparent in the navigation bar will make my color darker than what it is original. So I want to get rid of the semi-transparent value.